# How do I install something from the "Fedora Updates" repository on Amazon Linux 2?

Tags: linux, fedora, yum, amazon-linux, amazon-linux-2

I want a container image based on Amazon Linux 2 with [loudgain](https://github.com/Moonbase59/loudgain) installed. Loudgain apparently [exists as a package](https://fedora.pkgs.org/36/fedora-updates-aarch64/loudgain-0.6.8-9.fc36.aarch64.rpm.html) in the "Fedora Updates" repository. That repository is not included a default Amazon Linux 2 image:

```
bash-4.2# yum repolist all
Loaded plugins: ovl, priorities
amzn2-core                                               | 3.7 kB     00:00     
(1/3): amzn2-core/2/aarch64/group_gz                       | 2.5 kB   00:00     
(2/3): amzn2-core/2/aarch64/updateinfo                     | 473 kB   00:00     
(3/3): amzn2-core/2/aarch64/primary_db                     |  45 MB   00:32     
repo id                        repo name                          status
amzn2-core/2/aarch64           Amazon Linux 2 core repository     enabled: 19209
amzn2-core-debuginfo/2/aarch64 Amazon Linux 2 core repository - d disabled
amzn2-core-source/2            Amazon Linux 2 core repository - s disabled
repolist: 19209
```

What do I have to do to get `yum install loudgain` to work?